# Convert 64GB USB flash drive from exFAT to FAT32

Tags: conversion, fat32, exfat

I used a C400 64GB USB2 Flash Drive EMTEC green to record digital MP4 using a converter of VHS tapes and transferred them to a PC. This has worked very well. But a moment after I deleted one by one all the processed files, I found that by viewing the properties, approximately 2GB of the space remained occupied when no files were reported.

That had already been the case with key 8 or 32GB, because recording ended badly, and in this case I proceeded to reformat to recover all available space.

So I reformatted the default key with exFAT 64B and 32 kilobytes. But since then I can no longer use the key on the converter. As I do not know what the characteristics of this key were before reformatting, I sent a request for information to EMTEC to be able to reproduce the initial format that worked correctly.

But I received no response. I tried to format in FAT32 but can not do it because I have such options as exFAT or NTFS for reformatting the key. Who can help me find my intitial formatting Flash Drive

Comment: Could it be the $MFT?

Answer (score 1):

Its not the machine ... Its the flash drive that has exfat which is replaced with fat32 ... the difference is:

1.exFAT allows for higher drive capacities than FAT32.
2.exFAT has a larger file size limit than FAT32.
3.exFAT uses a free space bitmap while Fat32 doesn’t.
**4.FAT32 has greater support than exFAT.**
5.FAT32 doesn’t have file number limits while exFAT does.

Read more: Difference Between exFAT and FAT32 | Difference Between | exFAT vs FAT32 http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-exfat-and-fat32/#ixzz33fSRa32y

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution would be to find another machine and use it to format the USB drive to fat32.